# Generalize a function

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to generalize a function that takes a Hashset of two unrelated objects with similar attributes. I have some sample code below:

```
private IList<IDictionary<string, string>> BuildDictionary(HashSet<ClassA> ClassA)
{
    IList<IDictionary<string, string>> data = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();
    foreach (var a in ClassA)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> aDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        aDictionary.Add(a.Code, a.Code + "," + a.Name);
        data.Add(aDictionary);
    }

    return data;
}

private IList<IDictionary<string, string>> BuildDictionary(HashSet<ClassB> ClassB)
{
    IList<IDictionary<string, string>> data = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();
    foreach (var b in ClassB)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> bDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        bDictionary.Add(b.Code, b.Code + "," + b.Name);
        data.Add(bDictionary);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Thus as evident from the code, the two classes are not related but they both are in a HashSet and contain similar attributes (code, name). I have tried using the generic T but that failed due to the fact that I don't have the generic class T created. Would there be anyway to get around this issue without creating a new class?

Comment: What about a Interface for both classes?

Comment: Do you have access to both classes so that you could implement an interface?

Comment: You could use reflections to check if a class is "typeof" or "is" and use T "when T: class"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your source classes are sealed or can't be modified to a common interface, you can use accessors for the parts that are needed, as one might do in most LINQ queries.

Here's an example implementation. Note that `toKey()` and `toMemberValue()` could be named more appropriately, but this is enough to replicate what you are doing for any class where you can specify a lambda to retrieve the relevant property, and isn't dependent upon the class necessarily having the same property names so long as the lambda is written accordingly. `Main()` shows what it would look like to use this method for both cases.

```
public IList<IDictionary<string, string>> BuildDictionary<T>(HashSet<T> sourceSet, Func<T, string> toKey, Func<T, string> toMemberValue)
{
  IList<IDictionary<string, string>> data = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();

  foreach (var element in sourceSet)
  {
    Dictionary<string, string> newLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    newLookup.Add(toKey(element), $"{toKey(element)},{toMemberValue(element)}");
    data.Add(newLookup);
  }

  return data;
}

void Main()
{
  HashSet<ClassA> setOfAs = new HashSet<ClassA>(new[] { new ClassA { Code = "foo", Name = "bar" }, new ClassA { Code = "foo2", Name = "bar2" } });
  HashSet<ClassB> setOfBs = new HashSet<ClassB>(new[] { new ClassB { Code = "foo", Name = "bar" }, new ClassB { Code = "foo2", Name = "bar2" } });

  var lookupOfAs = BuildDictionary(setOfAs, x => x.Code, x => x.Name);
  var lookupOfBs = BuildDictionary(setOfBs, x => x.Code, x => x.Name);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class ClassA
{
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you own the source code to both types you can implement a common interface.

```
private IList<IDictionary<string, string>> BuildDictionary<T>(HashSet<T> someHashSetOfTs) where T : ICommon
{
    IList<IDictionary<string, string>> data = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();
    foreach (var a in someHashSetOfTs)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> aDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        aDictionary.Add(a.Code, a.Code + "," + a.Name);
        data.Add(aDictionary);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Interface definition

```
public interface ICommon {
   string Code {get; }
   string Name {get; }
}
```

And now apply `ICommon` to both types `ClassA` and `ClassB`.